# Find $n$ such that $1-a c^{n-1} \ge \exp(-\frac{1}{n})$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, upper-lower-bounds

I am trying to find the integer $n$ such that
\begin{align}
1-a c^{n-1} \ge \exp(-\frac{1}{n})
\end{align}
where $a>0$ and $c \in (0,1)$.
I know that finding it exactly is difficult. However, can one find good upper and lower bounds it.

It tried using lower bound $\exp(-x) \le 1-x+\frac{1}{2}x^2$. However, it didn't really work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\exp(-1/n) \sim 1 - 1/n $ while the left side converges exponentially to $1$, the inequality will be true for all sufficiently large $n$.

Somewhat explicitly, you want
$$ a c^{n-1} \le 1 - \exp(-1/n)$$
so it suffices to have $$ c^{-n} \ge 2an/c $$
with $n \ge 1$ (note that $\exp(-1/n) \le 1 - 1/n + 1/(2n^2)$ so $\exp(-1/n) \le 1 - 1/(2n)$).
Now $$ c^{-n} = (1 + (c^{-1}-1)^n) > \frac{n(n-1)}{2} (c^{-1}-1)^2 $$
so it suffices to have $$n-1 > \frac{2a}{c(c^{-1}-1)^2} = \frac{2ac}{(1-c)^2}$$

Comment: Can you explain why it suffices to have $c^{-n} \ge 2an/c $?

Answer (score 0):

You could chain you're inequalities in the following way:
$$1 - ac^{n - 1} \geq exp\left (\frac{-1}{n} \right) \geq 1 - \frac{1}{n}$$
Then
$$-ac^{n - 1} \geq -\frac{1}{n}$$
$$\iff ac^{n - 1} \leq \frac{1}{n} $$
Now, we can move all of the constants on one side and all of the variables to the other:
$$\frac{a}{c} \leq \frac{1}{n c^n}$$
Clearly, the left side is constant. On the other hand, we know that because $c \in (0,1),$ then
$$\frac{1}{n c^n} < \frac{1}{c^n}$$

Therefore, we can chain in the following way:
$$\frac{a}{c} \leq \frac{1}{n c^n} < \frac{1}{c^n}$$

$$\iff \ln(\frac{a}{c} ) < n ln(\frac{1}{c})$$
$$\iff \frac{\ln(\frac{a}{c} )}{\ln(\frac{1}{c})} < n$$

Comment: This doesn't work when $c=a$ is near $1$.

Comment: Whoops, did the approx wrong

Comment: Do you have a sense which of the two answers provides a better approximation?